Migrate the document library from on-premise to sharepoint online using SPMT tool
I have migrated the document library to the wrong sharepoint site using SPMT tool. How can i remigrate the same document library to the correct site? Do i need to remove the previous migrated wrong document library from the sharepoint online site? I tried remove the migrated document library and remigrate back to the require site, but the document library still migrated to the same site, which is the wrong site i have migrated at first. Please help.

To remigrate the document library to the correct site using the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT), you need to delete the previously migrated document library from the SharePoint Online site. After deleting the document library, you can remigrate it to the correct site by following the same steps as before. If you have already tried deleting the document library and remigrating it, but it still migrated to the wrong site, then it is possible that the migration settings were not updated properly. You can try updating the SPMT settings to ensure that the migration is directed to the correct site. If the issue persists, you can refer to the troubleshooting guide for common SPMT issues and errors: Troubleshooting common SPMT issues and errors.
